# Latex Enumerated List referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

In latex, when I'm trying to cross reference an item from an enumerated list, instead of getting 6.3, I'm getting 66.3,

My list is a normal list just like any other, only I'm declaring the codes below in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would kindly advise against such definitions since is a far more convenient and useful alternative in [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
  \item Some item
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,ref=\theenumi.\arabic*]
    \item Another item \label{myitem}
    \item Yet another item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
See Item~\ref{myitem}.
\end{document}
```

Note that different `label` and `ref` key-values are supplied, since the former includes a trailing period `.` that you don't want to include in the latter. Using `label*` inherits the `label` from the higher level in the nested environment.