# Referencing Enumerate List

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

First off, I realise there are a lot of questions on this topic, and I've had an extensive look at finding an answer to my question, but haven't found one; if there is a duplicate on this site, my sincere apologies. Now for the actual question...

I would like to create an enumerated list in a way that I can choose the label and then have a hyperref reference to this label. The accepted answer on this SE question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/ref-should-use-enumerate-label-name) *almost* does exactly what I want. The answer gives the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{S.\arabic*}]
\item a
\item \label{l} b
\item c. goto \ref{l}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to do exactly this, but I don't want to have to write `label=...` each time. Previously, I had used something like

`\newcommand{\alphanumbering}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\textit{\alph{enumi}})}}`

and then just prior to typing `begin{enumerate}` I would type `\alphanumbering`. When I use `\ref`, however, I just get the counter (which is `enumi`?), and I can't even use something like `\alph{\ref{1}}`.

I'd then like to extend this further, to write something like `\alphaarabicnumbering` before `enumerate`, where

```
\newcommand{\alphaarabicnumbering}{
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi} {(\textit{\alph{enumi}})}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}.} }
```

This then gives a list with first level (a), (b), ... and second level 1., 2., .... For example,

```
(a) foo
    1. bar
    2. foobar
```

I'd like to reference "foobar" as `(a.2)`, and other lines similarly. (Note that a naive reference would be `(a)2`, which is not what I want.)

For reference, see also [this SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113360/latex-enumerated-list-referencing).

Comment: You can use `\setlist` to change the default behaviour of the list, and `\newlist` to define your own list types. See the documentation.

Comment: Someone had asked for clarification on the `(a.2)` referencing, but has now deleted their comment; I've added clarification anyway.

Comment: Your posting contains (at least) two separate, and fairly unrelated, queries. This site works best if each query contains only one (main) question. Please consider editing your posting to (a) remove all stuff not related to the first main question (which, I gather, is about automating the `label=...` material), and (b) posting a separate, new query in which you bring up the remaining material from the original query.

Comment: I suppose one *could* consider it as two (highly-related) questions, but if so then really one is a sub-question of the other: I want to be able to reference in a certain way, but I merely gave a stepped description. The other option is that I'm misunderstanding TeX more than I realised: feel free to suggest which bits are unrelated, and I can edit the question for clarity! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I don't want to have to write `label=...` each time.

Since you're loading the `enumitem` package, you may want to make use of its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a custom enumerated environment that does the special labelling automatically. The solution is fully compatible with the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{senum}{enumerate}{1} % create a new, 1-level enumerated environment
\setlist[senum]{label=\textbf{S.\arabic*}} % define the labels

\begin{document}
\begin{senum}
\item a
\item \label{x} b
\item c.\ goto \ref{x}
\end{senum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume that by changing the `1` in `\newlist`, I can create a multilevel enumerated environment? How would I then define the labels? Alternatively, should I just define nested environments?

Comment: @SamT - Indeed, you can define new lists up to 10 levels deep. For the syntax on how to modify the labels at various nesting depths, please see section 7 on pp. 10-11 of the user guide of the `enumitem` package. (Open a command prompt and type "texdoc enumitem" to lauch a copy of the package's user guide.)

Comment: After a bit of fiddling around, I've got it working exactly how I want it :) -- I'll add my own answer which gives a MWE, so that other people looking at this question can have some more detail. I've upvoted and accepted your answer, not mine, though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE to give a few more details. To those who are very familiar with TeX, Mico's answer and a brief glance at the documentation (which has some examples, but not necessarily exactly what I want) will be sufficient, but for those like myself we need to do a little bit of testing to see exactly what's going on! Here it is below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{list1}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[list1,1]{label=\arabic{list1i},ref=\arabic{list1i}}
\setlist[list1,2]{label=\alph{list1ii},ref=(\arabic{list1i}.\alph{list1ii})}
\begin{document}
\begin{list1}
    \item \label{1} ITEM 1
    \item \label{2} ITEM 2
    \begin{list1}
        \item \label{3} ITEM (2.a)
    \end{list1}
\end{list1}
\ref{1} \ref{2} \ref{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you. Just for completeness: the two `\setlist` instruction may written a bit more compactly as `\setlist[list1,1]{label=\arabic{*}}` and `\setlist[list1,2]{label=\alph{*}, ref=(\thelist1i.\alph{*})}`, respectively.

Comment: Ah, you are indeed correct! Moreover, I can write `\arabic*`, dropping `{}`. Thanks very much